# Node JS : Allow only server side calls to my api

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, microservices

I have been racking my brains for a simple solution.
Lets say, I have 10 API endpoints in my Node JS application.

I have already allowed 3 of them to be public, the remaining 4 have JWT based authentication

Now I have 3 more routes, which will not have JWT and I need to only allow Server side calls. No browser or curl or postman, should be able to call them. How do I identify from the request object that it is originating from a server?

Or to put it in another way, how to I reject all cross origin calls to my api? As server side does not fall in CORS, they should filter through

----- EDIT -----

I recently came across a service that uses User Agent header to block server side calls.
Can i enforce User Agent header for my service and ensure that the header does not have browser agents. This can be hoodwinked easily, but as a theoretical solution, what would be the nodejs interceptor that discards requests whose user agent refers to a browser agent?

Comment: Are the servers under your control? If so, use some form of authentication that identifies them as such.

Comment: Basically, this is going to be a token decryption service : While, using Public key other microservices can verify JWT signature, some of them might need the payload to be Decrypted. 
I want to expose this decryption service to a very specific set of servers..
My idea is to host these servers in a DMZ environment but the UAA has to have public endpoints, too, because of login/token generation requests

Comment: Are you using docker swarm or kubernetes?

Comment: i am looking for a scalable solution. Right now, it is hosted in my private server on premise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [express-ipfilter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ipfilter) package and only apply it to certain routes you want to protect:

```js
const express = require('express'),
      ipfilter = require('express-ipfilter').IpFilter;

// Whitelist the following IPs
const ips = ['127.0.0.1'];

// Create the route
app.get("/securePath", ipfilter(ips, {mode: 'allow'}), (req, res) => {
  // only requests from 127.0.0.1 (localhost/loopback) can get here
});

app.get("/openPath", (req, res) => {
  // all requests can get here
});

app.listen(3000);
```

---

If you are using Node behind a proxy, you may need to configure the proxy to set a header with the actual IP and then pass the `ipfilter` function a function in the `detectIp` property to the second parameter.

Let's say you are using nginx and have it configured to send the original IP through the `x-Real-IP` header, you can pass this function to `ipfilter`:

```js
const express = require('express'),
  ipfilter = require('express-ipfilter').IpFilter,
  ips = ['127.0.0.1'];

app.get("/securePath", ipfilter(ips, {mode: 'allow', detectIp: getIp}), (req, res) => {
  // only requests from 127.0.0.1 (localhost/loopback) that go through the proxy can get here.
});

app.get("/openPath", (req, res) => {
  // all requests can get here
});

app.listen(3000);

function getIp(req) { return req.headers["X-Real-IP"] }
```

Comment: I have successfully used ip whitelisting before. But is there any other way, we can identify a server vs client request?
Lets say, i do not have ip ranges of the calling servers yet, or they have dynamic ip ranges

Comment: None that I know of, no. You could work with dynamic IPs, you can pass ipfilter a function instead of an array of ips

Comment: Ok, i will definitely check on this.

Comment: How about the second part of my question : How can i block all origins from accessing a specific endpoint ? 
Something like - "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : null   ??

Comment: Using this you can specify that just the server that is running the scripts (i.e. 127.0.0.1) can access the routes, in turn blocking all other origins from accessing the route

Comment: But as an attacker, i can also explicitly set my req.origin as null

Comment: ok, i think i will have to go with either ip whitelisting or Key based access

Answer (score 6):

You should use a similar authentication/authorization as for the routes that have JWT authentication from the clients.

This means that the caller service should also authenticate using a JWT token, having a special `role` of `service` or something like that (this is 100%  your decision on what convention you choose). That token should be signed by the caller and verified by the receiving microservice.

This solution has the advantage that it does not depends on the infrastructure, it works the same no matter where the services are deployed.